# Requesting Location Updates on Scheduled Thread

Tags: java, android, gps

The Android application I am working on requires GPS locations to be recorded every 15 minutes. In order to minimize the GPS usage to preserve battery life, I want to use a ScheduledExecutorService to start requesting location updates and then turn off the requests once a location change has occurred. My current implementation does not allow this because of the error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Which I know occurs because I cannot make LocationManager calls in a background thread.

My code to start the scheduler:

```
locationFinder = new LocationFinder(context);
final Runnable gpsBeeper = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                locationFinder.getLocation();;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"error in executing: It will no longer be run!: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

  gpsHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(gpsBeeper, 0, 15, MINUTES);
```

The LocationFinder class:

```
public LocationFinder(Context context)
{
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void getLocation()
{

    locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (isGPSEnabled)
    {
        try
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, updateInterval, distance, this);
        }
        catch (SecurityException s)
        {
            s.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void stopUpdates(){
    locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    isGPSUpdated = true;
    stopUpdates();
}
```

How can I do this without relying on calling requestLocationUpdates on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you'll run into with your setup is that if the app is killed by the OS or the user swipes the app to close it, it'll stop recording your location updates. You can actually take 2 approaches to having a timed location update interval, regardless of the state of your app (except if the app is force killed).

1. Use the [`LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)'s `requestLocationUpdates()` method to set an update interval of 15 minutes, using a [`PendingIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) instead of a [`LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to ensure you continue receiving updates without having to hold a reference to a listener. If you need to know whether you have already requested for updates, just use the [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to persist a boolean flag.
2. The other is using an [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule updates that will call an [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) (for running in the background) or a [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) (for running in the foreground) to call [`LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)'s `requestSingleUpdate()` method to get the GPS update.